# Jquery Show image for some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

On changing the select option i am displaying the image and on success of ajax call hiding that image .. but this happens very fast .. i want to display the image for some time say 2 seconds. how to do it

my code

```
 var div_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.display_image').attr("id");
 $("#"+div_id).empty().html('<img src="${resource(dir:'images',file:'spinner.gif')}"/>');
 $("#"+div_id).show();

  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"${createLink(controller:'s2PublicLifecycle',action:'UpdateField')}",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                  $("#"+div_id).hide();
                }
              });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `setTimeout(function() { $("#"+div_id).hide(); }, 2000 );`

Comment: + 1 for beating me to the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

use jquery delay:

```
$("#"+div_id).delay(2000).hide(1);
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XPNaD/)